# How to replace mobile home pex toilet supply line that looks like this…

Tags: bathroom, toilet

There’s a lot of threads asking similar questions but none with a pex toilet supply line that looks like this. The valve is at the top of the pex line not by the floor. I want to replace it with a braided line and hook up a bidet. How can I do this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Cut the PEX line somewhere in the vicinity of the green line.
2. Remove the crimp band holding the cut off piece of pipe from the valve.
3. Reinstall the valve on the cut off piece of PEX still sticking out of the floor.
4. Install your Tee adapter into the valve.<sup>*</sup>
5. Install the braided flex hose between the top of the Tee and the inlet to the toilet.
6. Continue to install bidet according to the rest of the directions.

<sup>*</sup>Steps 4 & 5 can be reversed - i.e. you can install the Tee to the toilet and install the flex line between the valve and the Tee. Your choice.

[image]

There are a variety of ways of cutting PEX, from using specialized tools to using a utility knife. The internet is loaded with information on how to do so.

There are a variety of ways of removing PEX connection rings like the ones you have. There is also a wide variety of info online about how to do so.

Making the PEX crimp-ring connection does require the proper tools. Professional grade tools are rather expensive for a one-time fix, but there are less expensive options available that will work just fine for a DIY job like this.

---

An easier possibility (requiring fewer tools, but with other caveats):

1. Unscrew the valve from the toilet.
2. Screw the Tee to the toilet.
3. Screw a flex-line between the top of the valve and the bottom of the Tee.
4. Install the rest of the bidet according to the instructions.

Notes:

- This method is going to require a reasonably long flex line (probably 12", you might need to go to an 18" line) to give you enough room to loop the flex around in a smooth curve that won't cause the flex line to crack/kink over time.
- It will also leave that full loop of hose waving in the air and not looking very nice. You may be able to loop the hose between the tank and the wall to hide it, but it still may not look all that great.